# How to setup Windows Authentication on Windows 7 development environment IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7.5

My overall goal is just to get the logged on users information for an Intranet site I'm developing without them providing their login (since they are already logged into their computer).  So far I just get 401.1 errors and it keeps asking for my login/password.  Even though I provide my login/password, it still won't let me in.

I've Enabled Windows Authentication from IIS > Sites > Default Web Site, added this to my web.config:

```
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
```

My Application Pool is setup as Integrated / ApplicationPoolIdentity for .NET Framework 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying it on the IIS Server, and it is not working... try accessing the site from any other client. If windows authentication works from any other machine, but not the machine where you are browsing it from, you must disable loop back check.

Method 2 > http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642